# Angular reactive form display

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to do an reactive form but I have some problem with the visual part ^^

Here is my html :

```
<form class="text-center" [formGroup]="requeteModif" (ngSubmit)="modifier()" *ngIf="tableSelect != null">
  <h5>Ajouter des informations</h5>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" *ngFor="let modification of modif.controls; let nomCol of nomColonne; let j=index" formArrayName="modif">
      <label class="text-center">
        {{nomCol}}
      </label>
      <div *ngFor="let infoTable of infoTable; let i = index;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
      </div>
      <div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Modifier</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: What I have now, visually]

What I want :

```
           Col1                    Col2  
           true                      A            Button (get true, A)
           false                     B            Button
```

[EDIT]
I have find a way to display it the way I want but I don't know how to arrange my code since I'm suppose to use variable..

```
<div *ngFor="let infoTable of infoTable; let i = index;">
    <input *ngIf="j==0" type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
    <input *ngIf="j==1" type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i+5">

</div>
```

j id the number of the columns, as you can see it's depend on the number of columns, using this way it's too static but I have no idea about how to fix it...

Sorry for my english
Thank you !

Comment: Look like a table to me. Please check https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: You have nested index variable sharing the same name. Rename the inner index variable.

Comment: Thank you for the index I didn't see it hehe, you're right Adnan, I want it to look like a table but I want to modify it... I want to have a form which get all the data form my database and modify it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer, I just have use the data_binding but I didn't knew how it works ^^' [ngModel]